# Cannot find color scheme error in Neovim

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I installed **[Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)** on Windows 8.1 using Chocolatey. 
But the problem is I cannot see any **color scheme** as shown in the tutorials.

I have cloned a [repo](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes) from `GitHub` to `~/.config/nvim/colors/` and it has all the colors including `hybrid`.
But when I included it into `init.vim` file this is the error.

[image: Nvim error]

Comment: What repo? What is the structure of the directory ~/.vim/colors?

Comment: Neovim uses a different runtimepath than Vim.  Are you sure you have the colorscheme in the runtimepath that Neovim uses?  See `:help xdg` and the output of `:set rtp?` from within Neovim.

Comment: its showing me ~/.config.

Comment: updated the question @D.BenKnoble

Comment: The answer is contained in the projects README. I will add a full answer later, but next time make sure to read the the README.

Comment: I already copied the content of colors inside my `~/.config/colors` folder. And added `colorscheme molokai` at the end of my init.vim. But it shows `cannot find color scheme molokai`

Comment: Are you sure, that `~/.config` is actually correct on Windows. In your screenshot you are using `C:\users\dell\Appdata\local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Colorschemes (in general)

When executing the `:colorscheme {name}` command, vim<sup>1</sup> searches `runtimepath`<sup>2</sup> for the file `colors/{name}.vim`. This is explained under `:help :colorscheme`.

#### Why We Care

If I wanted to install the `molokai` theme *by itself*, I could conceivably grab the [file](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/blob/master/colors/molokai.vim) form GitHub and put it in my vim<sup>3</sup> directory under `colors`. Then `:color molokai` would work just fine. But then my only recourse to update it would be copying the file again whenever I felt like doing so.

Things like vim [packages](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/packages/), [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), and other [plugin managers](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) were born to help with this. They have the explicit goal of allowing an entire repository of code to become a part of the runtime path. Effectively, this means that a repo with `colors`, `plugin`, and `after` can become a mini vim directory, having it's files loaded as within my personal vim directory.

#### Why We Care (part 2)

[`flazz/vim-colorschemes`](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes) is a *repo*. It's not one colorscheme, it's a whole bunch. So, either

1. Clone it to `$MYVIMDIRECTORY/colors`<sup>3</sup> ; or
2. Put it in a package; or
3. Use a plugin manager of your choice.

The key here is that the colors directory provided by [`flazz/vim-colorschemes`](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes) must be on your runtimepath<sup>4</sup>. Again, packages, plugin managers, or simply the base colors directory are the options here, each with their merits and difficulties. I recommend packages, but to each his own.

## Solving the OPs Problem

I suspect that the OP's main problem is where to put the directory `colors` from [`flazz/vim-colorschemes`](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes).

- "Standard": Put the colors directory in your vim<sup>3</sup> directory (such that `vim/colors` is the directory from the repo)

  - Benefits: extremely backwards compatible
  - Downsides: difficult to add new colorschemes to this directory, as it is now a git repository
- Packages: Put the whole repo in your vim<sup>3</sup> directory under `pack/{your_package_name}/opt`

  - Benefits: keep one plugin repo isolated from another, builtin to vim
  - Downsides: vim 8 required (not sure about nvim)
- Plugin manager: Do what they tell you to do (e.g. with Pathogen it would be at `vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes` or similar)

  - Benefits: plugin manager does a lot of heavy-lifting for you (Pathogen is different--it was effectively packages before packages were created)
  - Downsides: Learn a new tool, more requirements to making your vim config portable

Then make sure `color {name}` is in your vimrc/init.vim.

---

**Notes**

1. For this post, `vim` refers to both Vim and NeoVim
2. Vim uses (effectively) `~/.vim, $VIMRUNTIME, ~/.vim/after` (`:help rtp`). NeoVim uses the [XDG standard](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#xdg), so it's something like `~/.config/nvim` for Unix and `~/AppData/Local/nvim` for Windows
3. See #2: This is going to be one of `~/.vim, ~/_vim, ~/.config/nvim, ~/AppData/Local/nvim` depending on your vim and OS.
4. Note that this is pretty much explicitly covered in the [README](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/README.md)

---

[Based on the screenshot](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) in the OP, the `AppData` path is the right one for this Q&A. This can be verified with `:echo &rtp`.